# FOIA for legal fees?

Tags: united-states, education, fees, foia

I would like to find out how much my school district is paying a private lawyer to work on a particular matter. Can I use FOIA (the Freedom of Information Act) or a similar state statute for this information?

For purposes of this question, the "particular matter" is not a lawsuit exactly. It is the lawyer doing compliance work for the school district, such as attending meetings, following procedures, responding to U.S. Department of Education's Office for Civil Rights investigation questions, preparing and arguing a special education impartial hearing case, and other matters related to special education advocacy.

Comment: You can foia whatever you want; can't tell if they will comply. Hire an attorney: it would be a crime for us to help you.

Comment: We can answer this question if you re-word it and give some more information, such as your jurisdiction. For example, you can ask whether you can use public records disclosure laws to learn how much money a school district is paying in legal fees to defend a particular lawsuit.

Comment: I do not believe United States has any FOIA jurisdiction upon your school, it's usually a state matter.

Comment: What state? That would help. FOIA generally refers to the Freedom of Information Act—a federal law that only applies to the federal government. Most states have similar laws that fall in the broad category of Sunshine Laws or Open Records Laws: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_information_in_the_United_States

Comment: New York.  Here we have FOIL but I thought this would work as a general FOIA question.

Comment: @aparente001 State open records laws differ dramatically from state to state.

Comment: Because you're looking for information related to the relationship between an attorney and their client you may run into some roadblocks. I have seen organizations attempt to use attorney-client privilege to keep secret the fees paid. I've seen different states treat these fees with different levels of confidentiality. California protects all communication between clients and their attorneys as privileged, including fees. New York seems to be more disclosure friendly. Depending on the state, those roadblocks may just be temporary but will require extra work.

Comment: @DaveD - Can you point to a guide for the "extra work"?  Thanks.

Comment: No specific guide, the extra work is appealing and potentially going to court to force release of the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can always ask government entities for information.  If you believe that you have a statutory right to the information (e.g., pursuant to FOIA-like laws) then citing that statute and following its requirements for making the request improve your chances of getting a response.

However, ultimately it's up to the agency whether, and how, it will respond to your request, whether made pursuant to a specific law or not.  Some FOIA statutes provide specific avenues of appeal.  And if you think the government has neglected a legal requirement you can petition the courts for redress and see (1) whether they agree with you, and (2) whether they can or will compel the government to do anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

A lawyer told me how to do this: FOIA for the monthly invoices for legal services, during a specified period of time.  I have done so and am now in my waiting period.  If it works I will accept my answer.